# Recent update of homebrew has conflicting gcc dependencies?

Tags: macos, gcc, homebrew, gfortran, gcc4.8

**Homebrew 0.9.5**. Running `brew doctor` gives me

```
Warning: Some installed formula are missing dependencies.
You should `brew install` the missing dependencies:

    brew install gcc

Run `brew missing` for more details.
```

and then running `brew missing` gives me

```
ghc: gcc
haskell-platform: gcc
```

Yet if I want to link `gcc`, I need to unlink `gcc48` and `gfortran` -- but I used `gfortran` for `matplotlib` via `pip install`.

What caused this issue?